# Download image from GridFS with axios (React Native)

Tags: react-native, gridfs

I have the following function in my NodeJS server, that pulls an image from my mongoDB GridFS file storage:

```
router.get("/photo", (req, res) => {

        const { id } = req.query;

        const file = gfs
            .find({ _id: ObjectId(id) })
            .toArray((err, files) => {
                if (!files || files.length === 0) {
                    return res.status(404).json({
                        err: "no files exist"
                    });
                }
                gfs.openDownloadStream(ObjectId(id)).pipe(res);
            });
    });
```

It works perfect in PostMan, the image is displayed on it. However, I´m trying to download in my react native app and display to the user, but everything I got from my server is a empty array buffer:

```
const getAvatar = dispatch => (customer) => {

    console.log(customer.avatar)
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_AVATAR" });
    try {
        // axios instance
        server.get(`/api/customer/photo?id=${customer.avatar}`, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).
        then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
        })
        //console.log(response);


    } catch (error) {
        const { response: { data } } = error;
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_AVATAR_REJECTED', payload: data });
    }

}
```

Any clue what I´m doing wrong here?